# Unable to generate the ibm-application-bnd.xmi, ibm-application-bnd.xml,ibm-application-ext.xml from application.xml

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am using RSA 8.5

Note: I am using the existing `application.xml` file and I have already deleted the `ibm-application-bnd.xmi`, `ibm-application-bnd.xml`, `ibm-application-ext.xml` because these files are not in sync with `application.xml`. Hence I have removed them and only kept the `application.xml` file and trying to generate new binding files.
I have kept module id as it is in `application.xml` file. Shall I remove or keep it as it is?

I have tried below steps.

1. Right clicked on `application.xml` and opened with Application(1.x) deployment descriptor editor
2. Clicked on the Security tab and added the role
3. Then in websphere binding section, I have checked the checkbox for users/groups.
4. Under the Group section, I have added same role which was added in step 2.
5. Click on Gather button then popup message saying "No security role defined in Modules.

Please suggest the approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RSA, the highlight your EAR project, right-click select `Java EE ... > Generate WebSphere Bindings/Extensions deployment descriptor`. This will create fresh `ibm-application-ext and ibm-application-bnd` files.